# Why is npm prefix always set to system32 on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, system32

I've just installed Node v4.4.7 on Windows 10 but I am having an issue where `npm` doesn't find the package.json file when I run `npm install` in the proper directory.

The error I get is `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\System32\package.json'`
Which seems odd as I am not currently in `C:\Windows\System32` but rather `pwd` would reveal that I am in `C:\ao\AO Hybrid`

This let me to check `npm prefix` which returned `C:\Windows\System32`.
I've tried this with both npm v.2.15.8 and v.3.10.8 with the same results.

How can I make sure npm searches for the packages locally instead of in system32?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that my workplace has set the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` key in the registry to change my current working directory to system32, causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Git Bash rather than powershell.

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I did already resolve it and thus added and accepted the answer.